# Use the data fetched from generateStaticParams (Next 14)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13, generatestaticparams

I am a bit surprise by how generateStaticParams seems to work.

We generally retrieve one id in order to generate each segment.

It's fine but, the API call used to do that, contains as well  the necessary data to feed each pages that is going to be generated at build time.

But it does not seems possible to send as props the rest of the data fetched.

In my example, it means that at build time **At build time next is going to call ArticleAPI.fetchByCategory for each pages** with the parameter coming from generateStaticParams , while it could use the data coming from the fetch in generateStaticParams ?

So 1000 routes , means 1000 requests at build time instead of one that could provide the data for each page ?

In : /articles/categories/[category]/page.ts

```
import { ArticleAPI } from "@/api/article-api";
import { ArticleList } from "@/components/ArticleList/ArticleList";
import { Article, ArticleCategory } from "@/types/article-type";

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const articlesByCat = await ArticleAPI.fetchAllCategories();
  const params = Object.keys(articlesByCat).map((category) => {
    const articles = articlesByCat[category];
    return {
      params: {
        category,
        articles, // I though I could send this to the component ?
      },
    };
  });

  return params;
}
export default async function ArticlesFilteredByCategories(p: {
  params: { category: ArticleCategory; articles: Article[] };
}) {

  // But here p.params only contains the category and not the articles...
  // { category : "business" } for example when navigating on 
  //  /articles/categories/business

  // I wish I could receive the articles as props from generateStaticParams
  // Instead I have to specify a fetch here ( If I have 100 pages, 
  //I will have 100 api call at build time) while the data was already there in generateStaticParams()

  const articles = await ArticleAPI.fetchByCategory(p.params.category);
  return (
    <ArticleList
      articles={articles}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: I had the exact same question. I have many pages to generate and if I had to call the API again for each page it's a very unnecessary server load. I can load the entire data in the first call inside generateStaticProps itself. Did you find any solution? Or I'm thinking that maybe Next is not suited for this?

Answer (score 0):

when you build your app, next.js does an analysis to determine dynamic and static routes. By default [dynamicParam] route is considered to be a dynamic route. that means no caching strategy is applied. So, every time this route is visited, next.js will dynamically build this page and this takes time.

`generateStaticParams` helps you prebuilt page for each item in the database and this HTML will be cached. your app will be serving

`generateStaticParams` is similar to `getStaticPaths` in previous next.js versions. But before we could prebuilt only the most popular items and cache them if we had a large dataset. If a user visits a dynamic page that is not cached we could build it dynamically (if you remember `fallback` option). I do not think that `generateStaticParams` has such an option as of now.

Comment: Yeah I understand what it does. But that is not really my point. Is there a way reuse the data from generateStaticParams to prevent next to do 1000 requests at build time instead of one.

Comment: next.js has no caching mechanism for that. you have to rebuild all the pages